# How to get content of excel's temporary file?

Tags: c#

When I open an excel file, a hidden temporary file is generated in the same folder. I can open it with the TotalCommander Viewer, but I always get an IO exception when trying to open with powershell or c#.

```cs
new FileStream(@"D:\~$test.xlsx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
```

> System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file 'D:~$test.xlsx' because it is being used by another process.'

So how can I get the content?

Comment: Use FileShare.ReadWrite in the FileStream constructor.

Comment: It depends on what share access its been given, you may be able to open the file in read access, if not expect to write a file system filter driver, get the handle, then proceed to do what ever you like .however try the former first \*nods\*

Comment: Updated the question with the code snippet I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately for some reason you can not open the direct file, so I suggest another method when you copy a the file to a temp file, then read it and finally you delete the temp file, this way you can read it, I suppose TotalCommander uses the same method for opening files in Viewer.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CopyReadAndDelete(@"c:\Documents\~$test.xlsx");
}
static void CopyReadAndDelete(string filePath)
{
    var tempFileFullPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath), Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    File.Copy(filePath, tempFileFullPath);
    try
    {
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(tempFileFullPath))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd()); //or do anything with the content
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        File.Delete(tempFileFullPath);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you can copy it means you can open it, however you need set the appropriate access so the OS will allow it